# Changes to site and homepage will not fetch as google and not indexed either

Tags: google-search-console, fetch-as-google

please help. redesigned website and ever since then, homepage will not index NOR will it fetch as google. I keep getting failed on fetching.

any ideas? thanks! [My site](http://www.cervicalcancerhelp.info)

Answer (score 1):

Well the HTML is pretty old fashioned, but [google has indexed it](https://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=site%3ahttp://www.cervicalcancerhelp.info/&oq=site%3ahttp://www.cervicalcancerhelp.info/&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...1242.2702.0.3069.6.6.0.0.0.0.61.309.6.6.0...0.0.YV1LVinUlYE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=f712239cb6df72&biw=1920&bih=955). At a guess the JavaScript is getting in the way. That said some of Google fetch features in Analytics and Webmaster tools have been problematic this week so it may not be a problem with your site.

I would reccommend you implement [sitemap.xml](http://www.sitemaps.org) and google analytics in addition to webmaster tools as this can help matters along.

Also when checking to see if your site has been indexed always use an incognito session in chrome as you may be seeing locailsed search results otherwise.

Comment: I submitted a sitemap.xml again. I don't see it indexed (the homepage)  every other page is indexed and fetching just fine.

Comment: It worked this time! goodness..it's been 3 days.. thank you for your help! You are awesome!

Comment: @weez glad you got the problem fixed, if you're happy with the answer please accept it by clicking the tick.

Comment: Sure. also, do I have to submit both versions of my site? WWW and the non-www? Or do I just leave it alone and check the box to not use preferred domain? Thank you so much!

Comment: @weez best to pick one, point it to the other and stick with it.

Comment: ok, thanks! So, I don't need to add the other as a site then?

Comment: @weez add it where exactly?

Comment: webmaster tools ADD A SITE  the www version is the one that is added. Do i add the other version without the www or just set the preferred domain name?  thanks so much!

Comment: @weez right, provided both sites have the same content, you won't have to add them more than once.

Comment: @weez, when submitting a sitemap.xml or waiting for certain pages to be indexed, you have to wait a few days at the very least. Google will get around to it when it has time, the internet is a big place. Don't expect these kinds of things to happen overnight.